# How to define a function in python that takes as an input mathematica function and it's argument and apply to it.

Tags: python, math, physics, numerical-methods

I want to define a function that takes arguments as a mathematical function , it's arguments, and number of iterations (I am looking for the zeros of the function with the fixpoint theorem). 
I know how to look for the zeros, but I don't know how to make my mathematical equation take it's arguments from the function itself.

```
def f(function,x,iterations)
```

when I try to call the function something like this for example:

```
f(x**2+3,-1,20)
```

The function is taking already existing variables for x (that I have definded for another peace of code) and not the x=-1 that I am looking for here. 
The result I am looking for is +4

How can I solve this problem ? I have tried to define another function in my function but I am explicitly asked to have these three arguments for my function.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can the *mathematical* expression be a plain Python function '`def f(x): return x**2 + 3` or must it be a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, functions are first class objects by themselves, that can be passed as arguments. You can define the base function outside.

```
def my_f(x):
    return x**2+3

def my_functor(f, x, iterations):
    for i in xrange(iterations):
        x = f(x)
    return x

print my_functor(my_f, -1, 20)
```

Perhaps you can find useful a more implicit way of defining the same functor by using decorators.

```
def iterated(fn):
    """
    A decorator to make a function iterate over its outputs.
    """
    def iterated_func(*args, **kwargs):
        x = args[0]
        iterations = args[1]
        for i in xrange(iterations):
            x = fn(x)
        return x
    return iterated_func

@iterated
def my_g(x):
    return x**2+3
```

In this case, `my_g(3,1)==my_f(3)` will evaluate to `True`. That is, by adding the decorator `@iterated` over a function you defined, you can change its behavior to get the number of iterations as an argument too.

Comment: Thank you for your help, for my example this is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sympy` for evaluating mathematical expressions safely.

First, install `sympy`:

```
pip install sympy
```

Then, you can sue something like this:

```
import sympy as sy

def mathfunc(formula, **kwargs):
    expr = sy.sympify(formula)
    return expr.evalf(subs=kwargs)


mathfunc(formula="x**2+3", x=-1, iterations=20)
```

You can cast it as `int` like this:

```
>>> int(myformula(formula="x**2+3", x=-1, iterations=20))
4
```

or by adding `int()` on the `return` statement of `mathfunc`.

Note that I didn't use `iterations` since you didn't mention what you wish to do with it, but you can use it inside `mathfunc` as you wish.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is exactly what I needed. I need to learn more about sympy, it seems very practical.

Answer (score 0):

Store your function into a string so 'x**2' then when inside your function use the eval method to use the function. eval()

Comment: Using `eval()` might cause a [security risk](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).